# Changing Target in Shortcut with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, target, shortcut

I am trying to create a VBScript to change a target in a link

The current target is

```
"C:\Program Files\Hyland\Application Enabler\AEClient.exe"
```

I want the new target to be

```
"C:\Program Files\Hyland\Application Enabler\AEClient.exe" \\rrscwpappimg02\Workflow\CWF\AppEnabler\CombinedCWF.xml
```

Here is the script I have thus far. I keep getting an error on line 4 char 78:

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\AE Client.LNK")

lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files\Hyland\Application Enabler\AEClient.exe"      \\rrscwpappimg02\Workflow\CWF\AppEnabler\CombinedCWF.xml
lnk.description = "AE Client"
lnk.workingdirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hyland\Application Enabler\"
lnk.save`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Even just a script to create the shortcut that work on the desktop would work.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the complete solution for your problem :

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\AE Client.LNK")

lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files\Hyland\Application Enabler\AEClient.exe"
lnk.Arguments = "\\rrscwpappimg02\Workflow\CWF\AppEnabler\CombinedCWF.xml"
lnk.save
```

Answer (score 1):

The target path must be a string, so you need to change this:

```
lnk.targetpath = "C:\path\to\your.exe" \\server\share\path\to\file.xml
```

into this:

```
lnk.targetpath = """C:\path\to\your.exe"" \\server\share\path\to\file.xml"
```

Strings in VBScript must be in double quotes. Nested double quotes inside a string can be escaped by doubling them.