# TargetPath contains quotes, which cannot be written into a shortcut

Tags: vbscript, shortcut, double-quotes

The following is the command to be run.

```
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "WAU Manager"
```

The following "TargetPath" does not work because there are quotes inside the quotes.

```
Set A = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Desktop = A.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Set B = A.CreateShortcut(Desktop & "\Testing.lnk")
B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "WAU Manager""
B.Save
```

I have tried "chr(34)" in the following one, which does not work either.

```
B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn " &chr(34)& "WAU Manager" &chr(34)
```

The following ones do not work either. Doubling the literal quotes does not fix the problem.

```
B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn ""WAU Manager"""
B.TargetPath = """C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe"" ""/run /tn"" ""WAU Manager"""
B.TargetPath = """C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn"" ""WAU Manager"""
B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn" "WAU Manager"
B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn" ""WAU Manager""

Const Quote = """"
B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn " & Quote & "WAU Manager" & Quote
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Double the literal quotes `B.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn ""WAU Manager"""`.

Comment: I just tried doubling the literal quotes, which does not fix the problem.

Comment: Please read my question again. I have tried a few more methods, none of which works.

Comment: `Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")` `TS.Connect("DESKTOP-UCDGI39")
` `Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\")` `Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)
` `If tasks.Count = 0 Then` `Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered."` `Else` `WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count` `For Each Task In Tasks` `A=Task.Name`
 `A = A & " " & Task.NextRunTime`
 `wscript.echo A`
    `Next`
`End If`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129295/692942

Comment: @Lankymart, the .xml is **D:\WAU Manager.xml**. I just tried this **`TargetPath = """C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe"" \\server\share\D:\WAU Manager.xml"`** and this **`TargetPath = """C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe"" \\D:\WAU Manager.xml"`**. Neither of them worked. My .xml file is on drive D rather than a server or shared folder.